# Install 32bit or 64bit Centos 7 on an Intel Atom?

Tags: linux, centos, 32bit-64bit

I know there is no benefit to the hardware by installing 64bit OS on an Intel Atom 230 as its limited to 2GB ram. But on the software side, is most desktop software nowadays written for 64bit (Chrome, Office suite, printer software)? Will I have incompatibilities? 32bit still be updated as often?

For instance, I don't see a 32bit compatible epel.

Comment: There is a 32 bit version of CentOS 7 but it is a disaster to use. Best advice: Use a 32 bit version of CentOS 6.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like its upstream RHEL, CentOS 7 is *only* supported for installation on 64-bit x86_64 systems. RHEL is no longer built or supported for 32-bit systems. So there's no question; you will be installing 64-bit CentOS....if you keep that antique processor to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

See Red Hat's answer upstream, [Are 32-bit applications supported in RHEL 7?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/509373)

In short, yes multilib is still around, yes there is a desktop environment, no you can't boot i686.